# TO_ CHAR in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I am using oracle 11G and I know `TO_CHAR` is used to convert data into character and this query will work perfectly to get the day of the particular date:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (DATE '2019-08-15', 'Day') FROM DUAL;
```

But this won’t work:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (DATE '15-08-2019', 'Day') FROM DUAL;
```

> ERROR:        ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (DATE '15-aug-19', 'Day') FROM DUAL;
```

> ERROR:        ORA-01843: not a valid month

Why the above won’t work. I have checked NLS_DATE_FORMAT it displays “`DD-MON-RR`”. But in first query it’s “`YYYY-MM-DD`”.

What am I missing here?

Comment: it is because the "apostrophe" in the syntax, i have edited it  now it will work

Comment: Check the SQL manual for [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ). It is worth being aware of others such as timestamps and intervals while you’re there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Because `YYYY-MM-DD` is the string literal format in `date'YYYY-MM-DD'` with respect to **ANSI 92 SQL** standard.*

*For other format types, you need to convert explicitly, such as `to_date('15-08-2019','dd-mm-yyyy')`*

Comment: then how does this work **select to_char(sysdate,'day')from dual;** sysdate gives "dd,mm,yy" format

Comment: @johnjo `sysdate` is a pseudocolumn for oracle which returns the current date. `sysdate` is not a literal like other samples in the question.

Comment: `'YYYY-MM-DD'` is not a default, it is the required and only format as specified by the ANSI standard and the [Oracle docementation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ).

Comment: so i guess **to_date** we can use any date format and according to date format we can put "ddmmyy" like this **to_date('12-2019-19','mm-yyyy-dd')**   for  **to_char , truc, next_day** etc and all other date formats we need to use (date 'year-month-day',yyyy,mm,dd) so that is the format for literal string . am i right ?

Comment: @johnjo exactly, you're right. Even try without punctuation as `to_date('12201919','mmyyyydd')` equals `date'2019-12-19'`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is purely due to your NLS settings. if you run below query you can see the current NLS parameter values for your database

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
```

if you want to change your nls parameter for date please run below query

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYYY';
```